# Count number of same elements in the same position in two vectors

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
set.seed(12)

a<-sample(c(0,1),10,replace=T)

b<-sample(c(0,1),10,replace=T)

> a
 [1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
> b
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

I would like to count the number of elements which match in the two vectors.

So in the above case:

the following elements match: 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10.

I cannot do this with set operators because I'm not interested in the common elements, but also in their position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `which`  and `==`

```
which(a==b)
#[1]  1  2  4  5  6  7  8 10
```

Using @David Arenburg's example

```
 set.seed(12)
 a <- sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE)
 b <- sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE)
 c <- sample(c(0,1),10,replace=TRUE) # added

 which(rowSums(cbind(a,b,c)==a)==3)
#[1] 1 2 5 6
```

Comment: @Andrie  Sorry, I got in a few secs early :-)

Comment: If the goal really is to *count the number of elements which match in the two vectors*, then let's suggest doing `sum(a == b)` rather than `length(which(a == b)).`

Comment: @Pascal Many thanks for editing, It's my fault that I didn't notice it while copy pasting.